# How do I deploy .aspx webform pages with a regular html site that has already been deployed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment

There is a web site that I'm about to start working on that is basically all HTML and does not have any server side languages included in it. The person that owns the site wants me to add a new form to the site that would definitely need some server side logic. Since I know C# I would want to make the pages using C# webforms using VS 2010. The whole deployment aspect of this project is hard for me to grasp though.

I may be over thinking this whole scenario, but is there anything out of the ordinary i need to do in order to ensure that these new webforms get deployed with the already existing web site? What steps do I need to take?

Comment: What kind of web server? Can you setup .NET on it?

Comment: It will have to be Windows since we will need IIS.

Comment: Is there any session information or cookies that need to be shared between the HTML and ASPX pages?

Comment: Now I am confused. You say the site is existing.

Comment: The site is currently hosted on godaddy and fully functioning, I just need to add a page or two to it. Since i only know C# webforms, i wanted to know if I could make the forms then upload the pages to godaddy and have everything funtion. I have never done much with deployment so I wasent sure how it works.

Comment: @deanis probably not, most likely between my aspx pages though.

Comment: there is no problem mixing html and aspx pages in the same web site

Comment: @ahaliavfox okay is there a work around?

Comment: it needs to be set for working with asp.net with the framework you are working with that will be the main web site the other html pages will not bother

Comment: Hmm. To have any ASP.NET you would have to be running on IIS. If it's presently Apache or Tomcat or anything other than IIS, adding ASPX pages isn't going to work. But an IIS site can have HTML pages. You could copy all the existing HTML pages to an IIS site, add your few new ASPX pages, and that ought to work.

Comment: i see you got good answers from James deanis and Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create a new ASP.NET Web Site Project or Application, and copy all of the HTML files and dependent folders into the project. If there are a lot of pages this could prove cumbersome, but getting it to work shouldn't be too difficult.

When you deploy the application, you'll just need to make sure that the host is configured to run ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 2):

Just include the current html in your web application project and you can deploy everything together. GoDaddy has instructions for deploying asp.net web applications on their website.

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy's Windows servers support ASP.NET 4.0, by looking at their site.  Since the existing pages are just HTML pages and thus would only pass info to the ASPX pages via GET, POST, or cookies, then I don't see why you can't just drop your ASPX pages in and have them work.  You'll need a web.config as well, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run ASP.NET Web Forms, you must set up an ASP.NET Application on the web server.  If it is your own machine, you do it from IIS Manager (in Windows 7 it is under Administrative Tools).

On a hosted server shared by many customers, the hosting company has its own way of sub-dividing out the IIS to different customers.  So you have to follow Go Daddy's instructions on how to do this.  Don't expect to have the full freedom like you have on your own machine.

You can configure an ASP.NET application on an existing IIS folder with existing Html pages.  The existing Html pages will still work, but it will be confusing and messy.  Why not just create a sub-folder and move your existing Html pages to there, or create your ASP.NET application in this sub-folder instead?